# How to get an Entity for which a users key is held in?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

So basically I want to get the store  which a Person is in? Here is the Pojo code for the store ;

```
@Entity
public class Store{

    @Id
    Long StoreId;
    String Name;
    String Address;

  @Index  List<Key<Person>> Members;


    private House() {
    }

    public Store(Long StoreId ,String Name, String Address) {
        StoreId = StoreId;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Address = Address;
        Members = new ArrayList<Key<Person>>();

    }



    public Long getId() {
        return StoreId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String postcode) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }



    public void AddToStore(Key<Person> person) {
        Members.add(person);


    }
```

Here is the code that Creates a store and adds in the current signed in user (Google login)

```
/**
     * Inserts a new {@code Store}.
     */
    @ApiMethod(
            name = "insert",
            path = "Store",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public House insert(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {


        if (user == null){
            throw new UnauthorizedException("You need to authorisation");

        }
        String tempName = "cottages";
        String tempAddress = "Gogoland";
        String userId = user.getUserId();


        Key<Person> personKey = Key.create(Person.class, userId);
        final Key<Store> storeKey = OfyService.factory().allocateId(Store.class);
        final Long StoreId = storeKey.getId();
         Store h = new Store(StoreId , tempName,tempAddress);
        h.AddToStore(personKey);

        ofy().save().entity(h).now();
        logger.info("Created Store.");

        return ofy().load().entity(h).now();
    }
```

So the relationship between Store to person is one to many as you can see. So i want to be able to get the Current house of the logged in user and in turn retrieve the other "person"/members entities also in the object. Furthermore i would wish to also retrieve the "children" of the "Person" entities on the same store as the current user.

Furthermore How would it be possible to invite other people to join the users store via email?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Modified the question to make it a tad clearer. Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should filter by key since you have an index:

```
return ofy().load().filter("Members", personKey).first().now();
```

However if you already saved the entity with the .save() method, you can simply do this:

```
return h;
```